# Spherical harmonic expansion of a power function

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, closed-form-expressions, spherical-geometry

Let $f$ be an even continuous function on the sphere $S^{n-1}$.

Find a relation  of the spherical harmonic expansion between coefficients of $f^n$ and those of $f$.

Comment: perhaps you can give some more info? do you want a relation between the expansion coefficients of $f^n$ and those of $f$?

Comment: Would the answer $c_{l,i}  = \langle Y_{l,i} | f^n \rangle $ satisfy you, and why not?

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker: Yes, I would like to find a coefficients of the expansion of $f^n$, in particular their relation with the expansion of $f$. Will add this to the question. Thank you.

Comment: @Michael Engelhard: I would like to find coefficients of $f^n$ in terms of coefficients of $f$, i.e their relation.

Comment: this would amount to an $n$-fold convolution of the expansion coefficients of $f$, I don't see how anything simpler would appear.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker: Yes, this is what I am getting, but I am not satisfied with the n-th fold convolution...

Comment: There is, as far as I can tell, absolutely nothing special about the spherical harmonic expansion of $f^3$ for a spherical function $f$ over $S^2$.